# Dependency injection for derived concrete classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

Hope this makes sense:

I have two classes:

**ZombieRequest**

**VampireRequest**

They both have to dependency inject:

**ICreatureRequest** 
(which holds endpoints that *ZombieRequest* and *VampireRequest* must use)

They both derive from abstract class:

**MonsterRequest** 
(which includes a common method for both *ZombieRequest* & *VampireRequest* (validates the response sent back from *ICreatureRequest*). Also defines how it should be used as an API (success variable, error variable, and a sendRequest() method))

---

Here's like the pseudo code of how it looks:

*ZombieRequest* : *MonsterRequest*

~~ use *ICreatureRequest* API endpoint~~

~~ use *MonsterRequest* method to validate the response~~

*VampireRequest*: *MonsterRequest*

~~ use *ICreatureRequest* API endpoint~~

~~ use *MonsterRequest* method to validate the response~~

---

In my controller I want to use *ZombieRequest* and/or *VampireRequest*, but I am getting lost with how to actually get it in there and use it.

Do I make an IMonsterRequest and inject that in the controller's constructor? But then how do I use a ZombieRequest or a VampireRequest from that?

Controller:

```
Get(string someVariable, string anotherVariable)
{    
    ZombieRequest z = new ZombieRequest();
    if (z.SendRequest(someVariable, anotherVariable).Success)
       string zombieData = z.ResponseData    
}
```

ZombieRequest:

```
class ZombieRequest : MonsterRequest
{
   ICreatureRequest  m_CreatureRequest;

   public ZombieRequest(ICreatureRequest c)
   {
      m_CreatureRequest = c;
   }

   public MakeRequest(someVar, anotherVar)
   {
      var response = m_CreatureRequest.GetZombie(someVar, anotherVar);
      ValidateAndSetResponseData(response);
   }
}
```

MonsterRequest:

```
abstract class MonsterRequest
{
    public bool Success;
    public string Data;
    public abstract MakeRequest(someVar, anotherVar);

    public void ValidateAndSetResponseData(var response)
    {
        // read response and:
        // set Success
        // set Data
    }

}
```

But apparently I still need to supply a 'ICreatureRequest' when I make the object. Little confused.

Comment: It would really help to see code, its hard to contextualize what you want to do without it.

Comment: Thanks. I added a code example of how I want to use ZombieRequest inside my controller

Comment: *"apparently I still need to supply a 'ICreatureRequest'"* - What do you mean by that?  What's the actual problem that you're observing?  How are your classes actually defined?

Comment: Ok so now that you say that, I guess a solution would be to inject ICreatureRequest inside my controller constructor instead and just pass that along with new ZombieRequest(m_CreatureRequest);

Comment: But I feel like that is bad, cause it requires the controller to know about ICreatureRequest in order to use ZombieRequest

Comment: The point of an interface is that your controller doesn't care whether you have a ZombieRequest or VampireRequest. The interface should provide all the functionality needed to the controller. You get an ICreatureRequest into your controller by passing in either a zombie or vampire request object.

Comment: You _want_ your controller to know about ICreatureRequest rather than ZombieRequest. That way you can create new CreatureRequest classes later and not change your controller.

Comment: I added code on how the classes are defined. I'm reading your responses now

Comment: "You get an ICreatureRequest into your controller by passing in either a zombie or vampire request object."

I don't understand this. In my controller I can only inject ICreatureRequest, since that is the only interface I have. I can then pass it into the constructor for ZombieRequest to use it, and that is fine? To have a controller need to know it needs an ICreatureRequest service/API when all it wants to do is get a Zombie?

Comment: They are not. ICreatureRequest is a service with a bunch of endpoints, and zombie just needs one, and vampire just needs one

Comment: CreatureRequest is the concrete implementation, which already exists and i want to use

Comment: A miscommunication because of your strange class names. I expected VampireRequest and ZombieRequest to implement ICreatureRequest. In your Controller code, you are "newing up" a Zombie Request. This is _not_ dependency injection. You should inject the MonsterRequest into the controller rather than create a new one.

Comment: OK so what is your controller supposed to handle?  Zombie, Vampire or both?

Comment: You also haven't shown us where ICreatureRequest is implemented. As written, your code won't compile (I'm guessing that's your issue) since new ZombieRequest() requires an ICreatureRequest parameter. If your controller is implementing ICreatureRequest then you have a circular dependency .. which is .. either possible and bad, or not possible.

Comment: In my startup.cs i use addsingleton<icreaturerequest, creaturerequest>, where both are already implemented for me to use.

Comment: controller is supposed to handle zombie and/or vampire

Comment: imagine ICreatureRequest as ICentralApi instead or something, it's totally unrelated from what I'm making but I need to use it to make my stuff work.

Comment: None of this makes any sense really.  Why would a controller manage two different types of requests?  Why would a request object be responsible for making the requests (the request is what is _sent_ to a service that makes the request).  Why don't you have a response class?

Comment: Ok so can we call it ZombieRetriever or something?

Comment: This shouldn't be this hard, you have yet to clarify what it is you want.  What is your controller(s) responsible for?  Just retrieving a Zombie or a Vampire?   Is `ICreatureRequest` a _service_ that returns zombies or vampires?  If so **rename it**.  Will your requests to that service always have the same parameters?  If so, just make **one request class**.  You should also create one Response class that has a property of type T (ie generic) called Data.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is starting to make sense so I'll take a crack at an answer. You need to learn the difference between Dependency Injection and a Dependency Injection Framework (sometimes called an Inversion of Control Container or IoC Container).

Your VampireRequest and ZombieRequest classes are set up to allow dependency injection. Your constructors accept the dependencies needed by the code. Your Controller, however, is clearly not set up for dependency injection since you are newing up a request.

So, focusing on the Vampire and Zombie classes..

First, I'll suggest you could move the ICreatureRequest up the hierarchy into MonsterRequest.

More importantly, in order to use dependency injection and create a VampireRequest, you have no choice but to create an instance of ICreatureRequest first. Since you are doing the newing in your controller, you will have to get an instance of the ICreatureRequest there too.

As you identified, why should the controller know about a specific instance of ICreatureRequest just to use MonsterRequest? It probably shouldn't. So you have a few choices: 1) ignore this rule and just have your controller create the ICreatureRequest. 2) inject an ICreatureRequest into the controller. 3) inject a fully created MonsterRequest into the controller. 4) Use an IoC Container to create all your dependencies for you automatically.

You've already made it clear you don't like the sounds of option 1. If you go with option 2 or 3 you'll soon notice that someone needs to new up the ICreatureRequest to pass to the Controller, so you'll probably be back in a few hours. Option 4 is probably the gap in your understanding and pretty much what everyone is talking about when they say dependency injection. It's also a much larger topic than I want to broach here, so instead I'll just refer you to documentation for one of my personal favourites: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html